# Encoding for higher order functors with Lightweight higher-kinded polymorphism

Tags: module, ocaml, functor

OCaml unfortunately doesn't accept type variables ranging over type constructors :

`'a option`, `'a list` are valid, but `'a 'm` is not.

Thanks to functors (cf [so/Fix data type in OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995044/fix-data-type-in-ocaml)) we can encode fix point and range over type constructor.
We can also avoid using modules, and use only value-level Ocaml (*Lightweight higher kind* cf [higher](https://github.com/ocamllabs/higher) and [higher_kind](https://github.com/janestreet/higher_kinded) )

---

Some data structure like *perfect trees* can be described as a fixpoint of a "higher order functor" : the equivalent to the "underlying type constructor", before taking the fixpoint, maps a type constructor `(p: * -> *)` to another type constructor `* -> *`.

Can we encode perfect trees as such a fixpoint using the value-level (LHK) approach of the *higher/higher_kind* library ?

```hs
Perfect = Mu1 (p : *->*). Id + p ∘ Δ
```

where

```hs
Δ : * -> *
type Δ a = (a,a)
```

in haskell

```hs
-- stack --resolver lts-17.10 script

{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneKindSignatures #-}

module SOPerfectTree where

type Perfect :: * -> *
type Perfect a = Mu1 PerfectF a

type Mu1 :: ((* -> *) -> * -> *) -> * -> *
newtype Mu1 f a = In {unIn :: f (Mu1 f) a}

type PerfectF :: (* -> *) -> * -> *
data PerfectF f a = Leaf a | Node (f (a, a))
```