# higher order modules in OCaml

Tags: module, ocaml, higher-kinded-types

OCaml functors taking an OCaml functor as arguments, or returning OCaml functors are never mentioned in the [manual](https://ocaml.org/manual/moduleexamples.html).

Is there a technical reason that prevents OCaml to have higher-order modules ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Higher-order functors are supported and work as expected:

```ml
module type endo = sig
  module type t
  module F: t -> t
end
module Twice(F:endo) = struct
  module type t = F.t
  module F(X:t) = F.F(F.F(X))
end
```

The manual merely considers that it is a not surprising feature.

Comment: I see ! there is a stratification of sorts, as we have to wrap it in a module, but that's equivalent. thank you

Comment: ps : I imagine that can serve to encode those nested data type in the lightweight style https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70499424/encoding-for-higher-order-functors-with-lightweight-higher-kinded-polymorphism

Comment: There is no requirement to wrap it in a module, there are no differences between a functor and other kind of module types in this context.

Comment: like so 
```module Twice(F:S -> S) = struct
  module F(X:S) = F(F(X))
end```

Comment: the wrapping seems unavoidable to *return* functors though. not sure this is equivalent to higher order in the full sense.

Comment: The wrapping is also completely unnecessary to return functors: see for instance `module F(X:sig end)(Y:sig end) = struct end module M = F(Int)`.