# OCaml: higher kinded polymorphism (abstracting over modules?)

Tags: ocaml, monads, higher-kinded-types

Let's say I have a list of options:

```
let opts = [Some 1; None; Some 4]
```

I'd like to convert these into an option of list, such that:

- If the list contains `None`, the result is `None`
- Otherwise, the various ints are collected.

It's relatively straightforward to write this for this specific case (using [Core](https://github.com/janestreet/core/blob/master/lib) and the `Monad` module):

```
let sequence foo =
let open Option in
let open Monad_infix in
  List.fold ~init:(return []) ~f:(fun acc x ->  
    acc >>= fun acc' -> 
    x >>= fun x' -> 
    return (x' :: acc')
    ) foo;;
```

However, as the question title suggests, I'd really like to abstract over the type constructor rather than specialising to `Option`. Core seems to use a functor to give the effect of a higher kinded type, but I'm not clear how I can write the function to be abstracted over the module. In Scala, I'd use an implicit context bound to require the availability of some `Monad[M[_]]`. I'm expecting that there's no way of implicitly passing in the module, but how would I do it explicitly? In other words, can I write something approximating this:

```
let sequence (module M : Monad.S) foo =
let open M in
let open M.Monad_infix in
  List.fold ~init:(return []) ~f:(fun acc x ->  
    acc >>= fun acc' -> 
    x >>= fun x' -> 
    return (x' :: acc')
    ) foo;;
```

Is this something that can be done with first class modules?

Edit: Okay, so it didn't actually occur to me to try using that specific code, and it appears it's closer to working than I'd anticipated! Seems the syntax is in fact valid, but I get this result:

```
Error: This expression has type 'a M.t but an expression was expected of type 'a M.t
The type constructor M.t would escape its scope
```

The first part of the error seems confusing, since they match, so I'm guessing the problem is with the second - Is the problem here that the return type doesn't seem to be determined?  I suppose it's dependent on the module which is passed in - is this a problem? Is there a way to fix this implementation?

Comment: This old question might be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986374/higher-order-type-constructors-and-functors-in-ocaml

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, here is a self-contained version of your code (using the legacy
`List.fold_left` of the standard library) for people that don't have
Core under hand and still want to try to compile your example.

```
module type MonadSig = sig
  type 'a t
  val bind : 'a t -> ('a -> 'b t) -> 'b t
  val return : 'a -> 'a t
end

let sequence (module M : MonadSig) foo =
  let open M in
  let (>>=) = bind in
  List.fold_left (fun acc x ->  
    acc >>= fun acc' -> 
    x >>= fun x' -> 
    return (x' :: acc')
  ) (return []) foo;;
```

The error message that you get means (the confusing first line can
be ignored) that the M.t definition is local to the `M` module, and
must not escape its scope, which it would do with what you're trying
to write.

This is because you are using first-class modules, that allow to
abstract on modules, but not to have dependent-looking types such as
the return type depends on the argument's module value, or at least
*path* (here `M`).

Consider this example:

```
module type Type = sig
  type t
end

let identity (module T : Type) (x : T.t) = x
```

This is wrong. The error messages points on `(x : T.t)` and says:

```
Error: This pattern matches values of type T.t
       but a pattern was expected which matches values of type T.t
       The type constructor T.t would escape its scope
```

What you *can* do is abstract on the desired type before you abstract on the first-class module T, so that there is no escape anymore.

```
let identity (type a) (module T : Type with type t = a) (x : a) = x
```

This relies on the ability to explicitly abstract over the type variable `a`. Unfortunately, this feature has not been extended to abstraction over higher-kinded variables. You currently *cannot* write:

```
let sequence (type 'a m) (module M : MonadSig with 'a t = 'a m) (foo : 'a m list) =
  ...
```

The solution is to use a functor: instead of working at value level, you work at the module level, which has a richer kind language.

```
module MonadOps (M : MonadSig) = struct
  open M
  let (>>=) = bind

  let sequence foo =
    List.fold_left (fun acc x ->  
      acc >>= fun acc' -> 
      x >>= fun x' -> 
      return (x' :: acc')
    ) (return []) foo;;
end
```

Instead of having each monadic operation (`sequence`, `map`, etc.) abstract over the monad, you do a module-wide abstraction.

Comment: Yeah, I'd got to the point of assuming that it was the dependent(-ish) type that was causing the problem! Thanks for a very detailed answer.