# Is it possible to support higher-kinded types in Standard ML?

Tags: sml, language-design, higher-kinded-types

I have read in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986374/higher-order-type-constructors-and-functors-in-ocaml) that ML dialects do not allow type variables of non-ground kind. E.g. the last statement is not representable:

```hs
-- Haskell code
type Ground        = Int    
type FirstOrder  a = Maybe a
type SecondOrder c = c Int   -- ML do not allow :c
```

OCaml has support of higher-kinded only at the level of modules. There are some explanations ([here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jdy22/papers/lightweight-higher-kinded-polymorphism.pdf#page=2) and author's comment [here](https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/higher-kinded-polymorphism/2192/5)) about which features of OCaml clash with higher-kinded types opportunity.

If I understood it correctly, the main problem is in the following facts:

- OCaml does not follow a "freshness" restriction for type definitions: construct `type` can define both an alias (an the type will remain the same) and a new fresh type
- type alias definition can be hidden

AFAIK, Standard ML has different constructs for type definition and aliases: `type` for aliases and `datatype` for new fresh types introduction.

Unfortunatelly, I do not know SML well enough -- is it possible to export type aliases with its definition hidden? And can someone please show me if there are any other SML features that still do not go well with an opportunity of higher-kinded types?

Probably there will be some problems with functors -- Could one be so kind to show a code example of it? I've heard several times about such cases but still have not found a complete example of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, SML can express the equivalent of higher-kinded types through functors, and can also make them abstract. Useless example:

```
functor F (type 'a t) :> sig type 'a u end =
struct
    type 'a u = ('a t) t
end
```

However, unlike OCaml, SML does not (officially) have higher-order functors, so per the standard, you can only express second-order type constructors this way.

FWIW, OCaml may use the same keyword for type aliases and generative types (`type` vs `datatype` in SML), but they are still distinguished syntactically, by their right-hand side. So that's no real difference to SML.In both languages, an abstract occurring in a signature can be implemented as either a type alias or a generative type. So the problem for type inference that Leo is alluding to exists equally in both. Haskell can get away without that problem because it does not have the same expressiveness regarding type abstraction (i.e., no "sealing" operator for modules).

Comment: Did I understand correctly that if we forbid type aliases to be exported as is to guarantee that all types in signature are generative, it will solve the problem? Looks like not and that I stil miss another contradicting points... I mentioned the feature of the only type intoducing keyword in OCaml just because, even if previous statement is true and one want to prohibit exporting aliases it will be somehow clumsy to do it with only one keyword (though of course possible).

Comment: @AlexanderBashkirov, yes, I think if ML didn't allow abstracting over non-generative type definitions then the problem would go away. However, that would severely cripple the language, so isn't really a solution.

Comment: Is it really this much? Just to wrap all aliases with an additional `datatype` before abstracting them. In any case from the outer point of view on the module we can not say anything about the real type beneath abstract one, can we? So additional wrapping should not influence users (as I understand it). But for the type system knowledge that all abstract types of modules are generative is a big deal (I feel it even natural somehow). I do not know sharing constrainsts good enough, but I do not see any problems with them too.

Comment: P.S. I used term "sharing constraints" in OCaml-ish way, in SML it is `where type` clause, AFAIK.

Comment: @AlexanderBashkirov, that doesn't work in higher-order cases, because it requires deep copying -- which in turn restricts abstraction to pure data structures. As a trivial example, assume a signature `{type t; val f : int list -> t list}` where `t` is implemented as `int`. Or `g : int ref list -> t ref list`, where copying wouldn't even work.